# Where is Oracle sqlplus located?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, command-line, sqlplus

**Background**

Coming from a `mysql` background, I find getting started with Oracle quite a different experience.

**Question**

Where do I find this command tool for Oracle?

I have checked [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL%2aPlus) and it only says:

> An Oracle programmer in the appropriately configured software environment can launch SQL*Plus

And it's not in the PATH on my Windows:

```
C:\Users\jeff>sqlplus
'sqlplus' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can locate the `sqlplus` executable in Windows by running in a CMD shell

```
dir /s /b c:\sqlplus.exe
```

Suppose you find the file at

```
c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin\sqlplus.exe
```

Then you have determined that your ORACLE_HOME is:

```
c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1
```

Assuming the above ORACLE_HOME, set your environment variables (Control Panel > System > Environment Variables).  Below is example, so modify these to match the ORACLE_HOME you determined above.

```
ORACLE_HOME=c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1

TNS_ADMIN=c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin

PATH=  *(add this below the end of your PATH)*
         ;c:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin
```

Comment: the first command would work, but `dir /s /b sqlplus.exe` seems to be less confusing

Comment: @failedProgrammer, not quite.  Doing `dir /s /b sqlplus.exe` will show you all the sqlplus.exe found under your current directory.  To traverse your entire disk, you would either have to `cd \ ` first, then `dir /s /b sqlplus.exe ` OR as one step just `dir /s /b c:\sqlplus.exe`, which will search recursively from C:\ no matter what your present dir is.

Comment: upvoted for correctness, i tried other things but this still seems to be the best way. still confusing.

Comment: Life saver. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually in  $ORACLE_HOME/bin and usually they suggest to run

```
. oraenv
```

to prepare your environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Oracle Server on your local computer you can also find it by right clicking the running Oracle process:

[image]

In my case it is in

```
C:\app\TZNind\virtual\product\12.2.0\dbhome_2\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: For example, Missing files in WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home folder.

Solve: Reinstall oracle db. The exact solution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8J9P.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OFoA.png)